# SQL: Outputting month names in correct order

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the query composer on Google BigQuery.
I want to output the months in the correct order, e.g. starting with January, ending with December.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT month, gender, SUM(cost) AS Cost
FROM [medicare.medicareTable]
GROUP BY month, gender
ORDER BY month, gender
```

Without the `ORDER BY` above, the months were in a completely random order. Now they are alphabetised, which is a little better but still not what I want.

Using the above query, the output looks like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18r_HhY1jG3Edkj5Nk8gDM_eSQ_1fI6ePHSZuJuoAppE/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: I'm using Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for BigQuery Standard SQL you can use [PARSE_DATE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#parse_date). You can see [Supported Format Elements for DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date)

```
WITH m AS (
  SELECT 'January 01 2016' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT 'February 01 2016' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT 'March 01 2016' AS d 
)
SELECT d, EXTRACT(month FROM PARSE_DATE('%B %d %Y', d)) AS month_number
FROM m
ORDER BY month_number
```

Comment: @helpmeplz: I've deleted my answer. Mikhail Berlyant answer is correct.

Comment: Hey so I'm getting this error: "Encountered " "WITH" "WITH "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF>"

Comment: this is for Standard SQL - see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get month number from month name and sort is ascending order.

Syntax for SQL Server

```
select DATEPART(MM,'january 01 2016') -- returns 1
```

So you can try something like this

```
SELECT month, gender, SUM(cost) AS Cost
FROM [medicare.medicareTable]
GROUP BY month, gender
ORDER BY datepart(MM,month + ' 01 2016'),gender
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I put in your query and got this error: "Query Failed
Error: 12.10 - 13.20: Unrecognized function datepart"